# Googlesheets Apps Script append row and hyperlink

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

I have a code that appends row with every edit made on spreadsheet with the following details:

```
Date, Time, Sheet Name, Cell Location, User
```

Code is:

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var timestamp = new Date();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();


  sheet.appendRow([Utilities.formatDate(timestamp, "GMT", "dd-MMM-yyyy"),
  Utilities.formatDate(timestamp, "GMT", "E"),
  Utilities.formatDate(timestamp, SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "HH:mm:ss"),
  sheetName,
  sheet.getActiveCell().getA1Notation(),
  Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()]);

}
```

What I really want to do is make the 'Cell Location' part hyperlinked to original location using this function:

```
sheet.getRange(1,1)
.setValue('=hyperlink("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+ss.getId()
+'/edit#gid='
+ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetId()
+'&range='
+sheet.getActiveCell().getA1Notation()+'")');
```

So final code is:

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var timestamp = new Date();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();

  sheet.appendRow([Utilities.formatDate(timestamp, "GMT", "dd-MMM-yyyy"),
  Utilities.formatDate(timestamp, "GMT", "E"),
  Utilities.formatDate(timestamp, SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "HH:mm:ss"),
  sheetName,

  .setValue('=hyperlink("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+ss.getId()
   +'/edit#gid='
   +ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetId()
   +'&range='
   +sheet.getActiveCell().getA1Notation()+'")'),

  Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()]);

}
```

But this does not work. Any advise would be appreciated.

I suspect because I started that but with .setValue().. Just looks wrong, but I am not sure..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in what you have included as your final code, you did not include a range before your .setValue(). you should not even need .setValue in this case because the value you are appending is directly in the row. So you could try something like this:

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var timestamp = new Date();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();

  var link = '=hyperlink("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+ss.getId()
  +'/edit#gid='+ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetId()+'&range='
  +sheet.getActiveCell().getA1Notation()+'")';

  sheet.appendRow([Utilities.formatDate(timestamp, "GMT", "dd-MMM-yyyy"), 
  Utilities.formatDate(timestamp, "GMT", "E"),
  Utilities.formatDate(timestamp, 
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "HH:mm:ss"),
  sheetName,link,Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()]);
}
```